# Jquery UI DatePicker, getting associated input text for default date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using Jquery Datepicker UI 1.8.20 with some server-side asp:TextBox (creation).
To associate the Datepicker to the textboxes I add a class to them and then did the following after the body tag:

```
 $('body').on('focus', ".datepicker_input", function() {
 ...
 });
```

This works fine but now, I'm also populating this text-boxes server-side with a date (in a predefined format dd-MM-yyyy) and I'm trying to put the datepicker default date to be the same of its textbox but so far I haven't been able to do it.

A few tries I made:

```
 $('body').on('focus', ".datepicker_input", function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        defaultDate: $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-MM-yy", $(this).value),
 ...
 });
```

Error: Uncaught Invalid arguments

```
 $('body').on('focus', ".datepicker_input", function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        defaultDate: $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-MM-yy", this.value),
 ...
 });
```

Error: Uncaught Unknown name at position 3

I tried to debug the jquery in chrome to see what $(this) was and I got the window object, so I guess this is the problem. I don't know how to call the associated object to the datepicker...

**UPDATE 1 - Full DatePicker code**

```
$('body').on('focus', ".datepicker_input", function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        defaultDate: $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-MM-yy", $(this).value),
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
    });
$.datepicker.regional['pt-PT'] = {
        closeText: 'Fechar',
        prevText: '',
        nextText: '',
        currentText: 'Hoje',
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Mar&ccedil;o', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro',
                        'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Mar&ccedil;o', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro',
                        'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Ter&ccedil;a-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sabado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pt-PT']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your textbox is already populated with value, specifying just date format does the job. Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/239/)

HTML:

```
<input id="datepicker" class="datepicker_input" type="text" VALUE="05-april-2014"> 
<input id="datepicker" class="datepicker_input1" type="text" VALUE="05-11-2014">
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('focus', '.datepicker_input', function() { 
      $(this).datepicker({dateFormat:"dd-MM-yy"}); 
});
$('body').on('focus', '.datepicker_input1', function() { 
      $(this).datepicker({dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy"}); 
});
```

Comment: HI, never would try that since i had DateFormat after the first call (seel update 1).
Anyway, this did solves my problem. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
$('body').on('focus', '.datepicker_input', function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
    defaultDate: $(this).val(),
    ...
  });
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/47h3rvby/1/)

Comment: can you please tell me what does $(this) is in the context? Like i say, when looking with Chrome Developer $(this) returned window, but using your code worked too.
Note: I accepted Dave solution because of time and simplicity, since his solution did not required de defaultDate line

Comment: as shown in answer..on `body` `focus event`..this jquery method will loop all the elements with class `datepicker_input` and intialize the elements with `datepicker`..and `$(this)` will refer to the current element being intialized as `datepicker`..@FEST

Comment: thx for the explanation, this means I can have better performance if instead of $('body') I use the main parent element where I know my target elements are like. Thx ;) @Kartikeya